# Oracle Weblogic Server: java.net.SocketException "Too many open files"

Tags: java, oracle, web-services, ssl, weblogic

I get the following exception when loading the server with webservice calls:

```
<2013-nov-19 kl 0:23 CET> <Critical> <Server> <BEA-002616> <Failed to listen on 
channel "Default" on 10.39.21.109:28404, failure count: 1, failing for 0 seconds,
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files (errno:24)>
```

The machine that is used is an HP-UX.

If I look at these files (using lsof) that the application has opened I can see that there is a webservice connection that hasn't been closed.

```
java    19290 xxxx 2102u  IPv4 0xe00000038b2df680    0t2534      
TCP u30427.xx.yy:63565->u30436.xx.yy:36693 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

These connections increases over time and reaches the maximum allowed number of files, and hence, the ”Too many open files” is thrown.

The strange part is that if I use HTTP (without SSL) it works fine, however when using HTTPS/SSL I get this error.

Does anyone here have any clue of what I can do to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: After more analyses this case, it is cleared, the issue is a result of weblogic cluster configuration. “Open files” are waiting to close cluster communication between two nodes. See <BEA-003108> <Unicast receive error: java.io.EOFException" > Please see:
http://modj.org/home/aktueles/bea-002616-failed-to-listen-on-channel-on-listenaddressport/a7e2db8254aee4603e4ecaf98a43e85e.html

Answer (score 0):

BEA-002616

Critical: Failed to listen on channel "channel" on listenAddress:port, failure count: fails1, failing for secs2 seconds, e3

Description

The server listener will retry the listen after a short delay.
Cause

The server got an exception while trying to accept client connections. It will try to backoff to aid recovery.

Action

The OS limit for the number of open file descriptor (FD limit) needs to be increased. Tune OS parameters that might help the server to accept more client connections (e.g. TCP accept back log).

Please check below link

http://modj.org/home/aktueles/bea-002616-failed-to-listen-on-channel-on-listenaddressport/a7e2db8254aee4603e4ecaf98a43e85e.html

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Fusion Middleware active uses file's descriptors on Unix-like OS. You should up open file descriptors limit for your user (user that startup WebLogic Server):

add into the file /etc/security/limits.conf followed information:

```
weblogic soft nproc 32768
weblogic hard nproc 32768
weblogic soft nofile 32768
weblogic hard nofile 32768
```

(weblogic is your user), than relogin with weblogic user and test open file descriptors limit:

```
$ ulimit -n
```